# Where to download templates for windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Can somebody list out the tools needed to develop for windows phone? How do I test my app apart from the emulator? Are there test phones available? I don't want to go through the installation of VS 2010 express.

Comment: See my comment under the answer from @Dennis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the test tools [here](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9713250) (web installer).

If you don't want to use the web installer, you can download an ISO [here](http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/0/9/6092A6EA-8638-4F4B-BD49-4A8FF77B2E99/WPDT_RTM_en1.iso).

You cannot test your application outside the emulator - only on the actual Windows Phone 7 device - WP7 apps run on a specific subset of .NET Framework that cannot be compared directly to any other .NET application type. The actual phone is only available to small groups of developers for testing purposes only and to Microsoft employees.

If you have a commercial version of Visual Studio 2010 installed, you don't need the Express edition.

Comment: You **can** test your app on your WP if you have registered as a developer and have unlocked your phone (there is a tool called *Windows Phone Developer Registration*, it is shipped as part of the dev tools that you install).

Comment: That is actually implied if you have a phone right now. The phones shipped to developers at this moment are test-ready.

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need is at http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=04704acf-a63a-4f97-952c-8b51b34b00ce&displaylang=en which includes a list of everything that gets installed.  You sort of need to have some flavor of VS2010 installed.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need Visual Studio 2010 and the [Windows Phone 7 SDK/Tools](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9713250). You can use your pre-existing Visual Studio 2010 installation, or use the bundled Express SKU. That'll install the project template and emulator into the IDE.

Once the phones have launched, you should be able to deploy to the phone, and run it there.